# What kind of ants are these? Are these venomous?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found these ants on a small mango tree in front of my home. Could someone identify them for me.

Length: 2-3 cm

Location : North India(Chandigarh)

Temperature: 21-24 degree celsius

More info: They built a home out of leaves of the tree.

[image]

Comment: Found it from google images. Its weaver ants. Its not venomous but they can inflict painful bites along with formic acid spray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These ants are called weaver ants, they are in the genus Oecophylla.

'Helcium is attached relatively high on abdominal segment III only in Oecophylla'
http://www.antwiki.org/wiki/Formicinae

They use the silk produced by their larvae to bind leaves together to make chambers for their brood. As any ants in the Formicinae subfamily, they do not have a stinger. They can however bite and drop formic acid on your skin, which can cause irritation. They are used in orchard as biological control agents against pests.

Comment: You seem to be answering a lot of questions about ants recently. That's fine, but please try to add a reference or citation to your answers if possible,

Comment: This is a very broad question about ants, there won't be any useful citation for this because the question is too broad. With the name of the genus, Sumeet will be able to find all the information needed.

Comment: I think there is a real issue on this forum, wrong answers get accepted with no reference while I get in trouble for rightful identification. Forcing me to add references is irrelevant because none of them provide support for identifications based on the habitus.